# Trying to understand 3-thread Peterson's Algorithm

Tags: multithreading, algorithm

I am trying to adapt Peterson's Algorithm to work for 3 threads instead of the usual 2. I do know that monitors or another strategy would be better for 3 or more threads, but what started as a simple exercise to dip my toes into multithreading has now become a burning mission after several hours of attempting to debug and wrap my head around this. So this is the usual algorithm:

```
C1 = false
C2 = false
turn = 2

Thread1{
    while (true){
        C1 = true
        turn = 2
        while (C2 == true and turn == 2){
            //spin lock
        }
        //critical section
        C1 = false
    }
}

Thread2{
    while (true){
        C2 = true
        turn = 1
        while (C1 == true and turn == 1){
            //spin lock
        }
        //critical section
        C2 = false
    }
}

Thread1.Start()
Thread2.Start()
```

I got it to work no problem with 2 threads, but when I tried to add 3, some funky stuff started happening (mostly working, and then out of nowhere 2 threads' activities will be interleaved). Here is my attempt at a 3-way Peterson algorithm:

```
C1 = false
C2 = false
C3 = false
turn = 2

Thread1{
    while (true){
        C1 = true
        turn = 2
        while ((C2 == true or C3 == true) and (turn == 2 or turn == 3)){
            //spin lock
        }
        //critical section
        C1 = false
    }
}

Thread2{
    while (true){
        C2 = true
        turn = 3
        while ((C1 == true or C3 == true) and (turn == 1 or turn == 3)){
            //spin lock
        }
        //critical section
        C2 = false
    }
}

Thread3{
    while (true){
        C3 = true
        turn = 1
        while ((C1 == true or C2 == true) and (turn == 1 or turn == 2)){
            //spin lock
        }
        //critical section
        C3 = false
    }
}

Thread1.Start()
Thread2.Start()
Thread3.Start()
```

It acts like it is so close to being right, but as I am starting to figure out, feeling "close to right" in multithreading can often mean you are still miles off.

Is my assumption about the 3-thread Peterson's Algorithm correct, or am I missing something here? I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't look like your new while conditions are symmetrical to the condition you used with 2 threads. You had `while (C2 == true and turn == 2)` so I believe you should have `((C2 == true and turn == 2 ) or (C3 == true and turn == 3))`  At least that would seem to preserve the logic behind the condition. Whether this is even feasible for 3 threads I don't really know.

Comment: Thank you! Still doesn't work, but I am beginning to think this algorithm can't be modified to support 3 or more threads. Because the logic changes the turn before hitting the spin lock, it seems that a third thread can change the spin lock conditions while another thread is in the critical section, allowing another thread to get in at the same time.

Comment: Look at the Wikipedia page for the Peterson's lock (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson's_algorithm); it contains a version for multiple threads.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! No idea how I missed that. I am trying to wrap my head around it now!